# Matching values in a comma seprated field in Redshift

Tags: sql, csv, subquery, amazon-redshift, sql-like

I have 2 tables in `Redshift` as follows:

```
T1:

QID   EID
Q1    a.1,a.2
Q2    a.5,a.4,a.8
Q3    a.7
Q4    a.3,a.5
```

and

```
T2:

EIDs
a.1
a.2
a.4
a.7
```

I would like to select only the records from `T1` that contain any value available in `T2.EIDs`.
So if any of the values present in `T2.EIDs` is available in the comma seprated field `T1.EID`, then I want to select that record from `T1`. For the given example, here's the resultset I want:

```
QID   EID
Q1    a.1,a.2
Q2    a.5,a.4,a.8
Q3    a.7
```

I know the `LIKE` and `SIMILAR TO` clauses would be at play here, but I can't seem to come up with something that would make it work.

The final query could look something like:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON <cannot think of a proper join condition>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a chance to fix that broken data model? That is the only proper solution to this problem.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Unfortunately I cannot fix the data model right now. But the answer posted below does the trick without changing the data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a poor data model. Each and every value in the CSV list should be stored in a different row rather than concatenated in a string. Then query would be easy to write and efficient.

For your current design, you can use string functions like this:

```
select t1.*
fom t1
where exists (select 1 from t2 where ',' || t1.eid || ',' like '%,' || t2.eid || ',%')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. It works great, except for a small typo that I had to correct. The `exists` condition has `t2.eid,`. The comma should be removed to make it work.

It is indeed a poor data model, but that's what I have to work with at the moment.